# How can I put a specific amount of integers on one line in python?

Tags: python

In my GCSE Comp Study lesson, I have been given a problem which requires me to ask for an input and then display square numbers until the input, with 5 values on each line. I managed to get to the point where it displays the square numbers, but then it is not letting me put 5 values on each line. Here is my code:

```
counter = 0
number  = int(input('Enter a number'))
for i in range (1, number + 1):
    print (i * i.)
    counter = counter + 1 
if counter % 5 == 0:
    print \
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The idea could be to enter them all with space as separator, then split the input ... and handle the resulting list of numbers.

Comment: Could you also give sample input and expected output to make this clear and easier to understand help?

Answer (score 0):

Python will automatically set a `\n` as value for the `end` parameter in the `print()` function, so you could work your way around it by manually setting it as a space, and only printing a newline when you reach a multiple of 5 with the counter.

Here is a **Python 3** solution:

```
counter = 0
number  = int(input('Enter a number: '))
for i in range (1, number + 1):
    print (i * i, end=' ')
    counter += 1 
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        print ("\n")
```

If you are using **Python 2**, just modify the first print statement with:

```
print i * i,
```

In the case of Python 2, the ending comma will automatically replaced the default ending `newlinw` with a space.

So that if you input `20`, the output will be:

```
1 4 9 16 25 

36 49 64 81 100 

121 144 169 196 225 

256 289 324 361 400
```

Comment: Your answer will probably not work for the OP because he seems to be using Python2 (because of his last line of code `print \` without brackets)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I agree. Python2 instructions added.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above may work fine for Python 3, but as you seem to be using Python 2, it will probably not work for you, so I provide you with a solution for Python 2.

You could make a list with the square numbers, and when `counter % 5 == 0`, you print the numbers joined with spaces and reset the list to empty:

```py
counter = 0
number  = int(input('Enter a number'))
sqlist = [] # list of square numbers

for i in range(1, number + 1):
    # append the square number to the list
    sqlist.append(str(i ** 2)) # ** is the potency operator in Python
    counter += 1 
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        print " ".join(sqlist)
        del sqlist[:] # reset the list
```

Answer (score 0):

"Square numbers until the input" suggests that you should print square values that are <= to the input.  Your code prints a number of squares based on the input.

A while loop would be the better approach to cap the squared values to the input.  To print 5 on the same line, you need to prevent the first four from going to the next line which you can do using the `end=` parameter of the print function.

In case the number of squares to print is not a multiple of 5, you will also need to add an extra end of line print() call at the end of the loop.

```
N = 123  # int(input("enter a number: "))
n = 1
while n*n<=N:
    print(n*n,end=" " if n%5 else "\n") # next line on multiples of 5
    n += 1
if (n-1)%5: print() # additional end of line if not multiple of 5 printed
```

output:

```
1 4 9 16 25
36 49 64 81 100
121
```